# I am trying to develop an Add-In for Microsoft Word on macOS. I am not familiar with Microsoft doc, could somebody bring me in the right direction?

Tags: macos, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am trying to develop an Add-In for Microsoft Word on macOS. The Windows version of the Add-In is already in development, but I don't have access to its source code. It seems like the following is the 'landing' page for developing Add-Ins for Office:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/

The above documentation seems to say that Add-Ins have to developed using web-technologies, and, upon examination of existing, Third-party, Add-Ins, this seems to be the case at least for the UI. What I don't understand, is, if the entire plugin has to be written using web-oriented languages, or if there is a macOS oriented SDK that allows to implement at least the underlying logic using a macOS native SDK, perhaps using Objective-C or Swift. I was hoping that somebody more expert could bring me in the right direction. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no platform specific SDK for developing Office add-ins. You can use web technologies for developing cross-platform Office add-ins, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins for more information.

You also can use `AppleScript` for automating tasks in Word on the MacOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene, thus the Graph SDK and the so called Authentication SDK are not related to Add-Ins development ? Thanks

Comment: These are extra tools for web add-ins. But they can be used everywhere, not only in the Office add-ins.